# Content from word to Richtexbox

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode, richtextbox

I'm trying to copy an equation from word into a richtextbox control in winform.
The copy and the paste are done normally.But the paste of the equation is done as an image not as an equation file.(I cannot decode the pasted element in order to get the unicode text from it).
Is there a way to conserve the original component type after the paste is done ? 
Or convert the image file to equation and get the unicode text from it ?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you show us your code that you are using to perform this function please

Comment: The case is reproduced without a code.
1)Open word document
2)Add equation and copy it.
3)Paste the equation inside a richtextbox
4)Copy the pasted data into word document again,you will notice that the data is as an image format not equation.

Comment: My guess is Word placed several versions of the object on the clipboard and Image was the first one the RichTextBox recognized. For Word you can probably use Paste Special... to paste the object, no such choice in RichTextBox.